# Put HTML in a Web View

Tags: html, xcode

Is there any way to put HTML like the one provided here: https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/ in a Webview in Xcode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the iframe URL you get on this website, and load it in the `UIWebView` like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: @"http://your_url" cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:your_UIWebView];
```

Do not forget to replace the URL string and your UIWebView delegate.

Comment: 1. You should remove `start` per the documentation for that method, which says, "Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method and provide `NO` for the `startImmediately` parameter." 2. Why use mutable request? 3. Why would you use `NSURLConnection` rather than just calling the web view's `loadRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` support `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`, which allows you to directly load HTML source (in a string variable) into a web view.